# Showing a WordPress webpage using an iFrame

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, responsive-design

I'm trying to host my webpage in another location.  my webpage is a WordPress webpage and uses responsive text to determine if a cellphone, tablet or PC is viewing the page.

Currently I use the following...

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe
  src="http://mymainsite.com/subfolder"
  frameborder="0"
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  scrolling="no">
</frameset>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

This works great when viewing on a PC but the issue happens when you view it on a phone or tablet...  The response text is not getting translated to the site so that it renders correctly is my guess.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix your problem, but please don't do this. Transfer the files them setup a redirect from the old domain.

Comment: Well that's not a helpful comment...  If I could do that I would not be posting this question in the first place.  This is a temporary fix and I don't want to just use redirects because the target url does not need to be known to the public.

Comment: I'm just saying using iframes is highly impractical except under certain circumstances.

Comment: Understood and agree...  This is one of two times I have ever used an iframe...  I hate them but this is one of those situations.

Comment: Okay I guess if you have no other option.